# I get an error that my app is only available for iPhones, while trying to install on iPhones, after store release

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

[image]

This is quite weird. After my app getting approved, I release it in the app store but can't install it on any device. Tested with iPhone SE, 6S, 7 Plus.

In XCode my targeted device family is "1".

Answer (score 0):

If your app already installed in your phone through IPA or through data cable, then first remove that app and try to reinstall it from app store, it will work. Also check your deployment target is same or under with your ios version.

Comment: It was unrelated, just a delay in the App Store, installs fine now. Thanks for the info thought.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is related to an App Store delay, it's not device type issue.